# Trouble Using Dynaform of primefaces extensions - jSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am getting following error while integrating [primefaces-extensions dynaform](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/dynaform/basicUsage.jsf)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaFormRenderer.preRenderLabel(DynaFormRenderer.java:280)
 at org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaFormRenderer.encodeMarkup(DynaFormRenderer.java:99)
        at org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaFormRenderer.encodeEnd(DynaFormRenderer.java:78)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
```

I have following libraries included in my classpath, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/wiki/GettingStarted)

> primefaces-3.3.1.jar
>
> primefaces-extensions-0.5.1.jar
>
> commons-lang.jar

Xhtml looks like

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/base.xhtml"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

 <ui:define name="content">
  <pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" >
  </pe:dynaForm>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**UPDATE**:

getting below error after updating some code:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier "_mainForm_dynaFormGroup" referenced from "j_idt7:dynaForm:j_idt14".
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getting below error after updating some code:
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier "_mainForm_dynaFormGroup" referenced from "j_idt7:dynaForm:j_idt14".
> ```
>
> what am i missing?

As the message states you're referencing an element with the id `_mainForm_dynaFormGroup`. This element can not be found. A common cause for this problem is that this element is in a form or some other container which prefixes the element id with the id of the container.

For example having this JSF:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <div id="div" ...
</h:form>
```

Will generate this HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <div id="form:div" ...
</form>
```

When referencing elements in another container you need to start referencing at the root using a `:` as a prefix.

```
<h:form id="buttonForm">
    <p:button id="button" ...
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <p:button update=":buttonForm:button" ...
</h:form>
```

Comment: and if the buttonForm is inside some panel, say formPanel then should it be `:formPanel:buttonForm:button` ?

Comment: @mashit no, a panel is not a HTML 'container' element (I don't know the exact name). Only elements like a form or a datatable append an id ;-)

Comment: ok. and what would this this expression mean?  `_mainForm_dynaFormGroup _mainForm_inputValues` Ref: http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/dynaform/basicUsage.jsf

Comment: problem is i am unable to use `_mainForm_dynaFormGroup _mainForm_inputValues.` may i dont have those elements present on my page. but i am using the example given on the reference page.

Comment: @mashit You can try to use binding. See [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406778/update-component-without-specifying-the-absolute-client-id/12410852#12410852).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following into your web.xml to use `_` instead of default `:` for widget matching:

```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR</param-name>
      <param-value>_</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

also you have to make sure that widget you are doing lookup for reside inside given form name.

Comment: yes, i got the point of elements look-up inside forms. thnx for the answer. i was missing this. i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward answer which beginners may find it easy.
 according to your exception `"javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier "_mainForm_dynaFormGroup" referenced from "j_idt7:dynaForm:j_idt14""`
you are referring `_mainForm_dynaFormGroup` from dynaForm instead of `dynaFormGroup` because your `dynaform` is not inside any container.

Here is one more example `Cannot find component with identifier "_mainForm_dynaFormGroup" referenced from "A4759:projectTab:dynaForm:j_idt581".` Here I am referring `_mainForm_dynaFormGroup` from `_projectTab_dynaForm` insted of `_mainForm_dynaForm` it has to be `_projectTab_dynaFormGroup`. Reason behind this is well explained above by @siebz0r.