# Update component without specifying the absolute client id

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

The code fragment below represents an editor. In my application, a windows displays a group of editors in a tab panel, each tab containing a datatable with the editors as rows. When a node is selected, its text will be displayed in the *organizationUnit* input text. The editor shouldn't know about it's parents. Is it possible to update organizationUnit without using the absolute client id?

```
<p:tabView value="#{accountsBean.groups}" var="group">
    <p:tab title="#{eval.getString(group.name)}">
        <p:dataTable value="#{group.editors}"
            var="editor">                       
            <p:column>
                 <custom:include src="#{editor.component}">
                     <ui:param name="bean" value="#{editor.beanName}"/>
                     <ui:param name="mandatory" value="#{editor.mandatory}"/>
                     <ui:param name="name" value="#{editor.name}"/>
                 </custom:include>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>                        
</p:tabView>

<h:panelGrid id="containerEditor" columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="#{name}: #{mandatory ? '*' : ''}" />
    <p:tree value="#{bean.root}" var="node" selectionMode="single" selection="#
        {selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{bean.onNodeSelect}"
            update="update_organization_unit" immediate="true" />
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
    <h:outputText />
    <p:inputText id="organizationUnit" value="#{bean.selectedItemPath}"
        disabled="true" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

The tab panel is inside a form called *form* with prependId="false"

Comment: I have a very hard time understanding your question, what stops you from using `update="organizationUnit"`? You should also make it clear that the lower part of your code is some kind of component, and post the full code of custom:include

Comment: @RasmusFranke I understood the question and it does relate with the code. And he can't do that because the `<p:inputText`> and the `<p:ajax>` are inside different NamingContainers.

Comment: The ajax event is inside a naming container that lies inside the naming container of the inputText. I think JSF looks in parent containers if the id does not exist in the current container.

Comment: I get this if I use organizationUnit in the update statement SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "organizationUnit" referenced from "j_idt85:0:j_idt88:4:j_idt903:j_id647446661_47d7f77b:j_idt2".

Comment: The ajax event is inside the p:treeTable, which is a naming container, and the input text has the datatable as the naming container.

Comment: @RasmusFranke See the algorithm here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent(java.lang.String). This case falls under the "Otherwise, search up the parents of this component. If a NamingContainer is encountered, it will be the base.". JSf will search up, find the `<p:tree>` that is a NamingContainer, and use it as the base.

Comment: Ah true. You could pass in the name of organizationUnits namingContainer as a parameter to editor.component, and refer to it both in the id of inputText and the update attribute of the ajax event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have components inside different NamingContainers, and those are not nested**, you must use absolute client id.

In your case, if you don't use the separator character at the begining, the findComponent algorithm would search up until it finds a NamingContainer: this would be your `p:tree`. Then it would try to find the component inside the `p:tree`, since it's not there, the exception you mentioned is thrown.

On the other hand, If you *do* use the separator character at the begining, you must use the absolute client id.

Short answers: No. Unless you change the way your components are organized, you can't update *organizationUnit* without using the absolute client id.

---

** If NamingContainers are nested, components inside the *outter* NamingContainer may update ones inside an *inner* NamingContainer by referencing their id before the id of the actual component they want to update, for example: `update="innerContainer1Id:componentId"`, or even `update="innerContainer1Id:innerContainer2:componentId"`.

---

[Algorithm is explained in the JavaDoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

A common 'trick' I use to avoid refering to ids is to use binding.

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <p:button binding="#{button}" ...
</h:form>

....
<p:button update=":#{button.clientId}" ...
```

**Note:** This doesn't work for some tags like `h:outputText` that don't generate an id.